# install python module custom location, PYTHONUSERBASE / virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to install a Python package I made into a custom location on Windows 7 64 bit.
According the instructions on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/reusable-apps/
I am running the command:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Now this installs fine.  It installs to the default location of

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages
```

However, I want to install to `C:\mysite`.
I read a lot about several ways, but what would be the easiest and simplest method?

The tutorial says use virtualenv.  I have installed that and never used it though.
Also there is this:  http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

The above method lists 3 ways to do this.  I would like to know how to use the "-user" option and customize `PYTHONUSERBASE` method

AND

The `virtualenv` method.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/

talks about this.  Anyone try this successfully in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add C:\mysite to your PYTHONPATH.

Then, when installing a new module, you do:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\mysite python setup.py install --install-lib C:\mysite
```

Source: http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Installing_a_Python_module

Comment: That is one method, but I read this from the link
http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations



There are older ways to achieve custom installation using various easy_install and setup.py install options, combined with PYTHONPATH and/or PYTHONUSERBASE alterations, but all of these are effectively deprecated by the User scheme brought in by PEP-370 in Python 2.6